# excel display only explicitly entered zeros

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel worksheet in which I have fields that do not apply to every record, and when those fields do not apply I leave them blank.  There are other fields that contain zero values which for some records have nonzero values, and thus I need the zero values for calculation purposes, but to display them would make the sheet far more difficult to read.  For the most part this works well, as I have suppressed display of zero values.

Occasionally, however, I explicitly enter a zero value in one or both of two fields, and when I enter those zeroes I want Excel to display those values.  I have read a number of entries on number formatting and none of them seem to do the trick, or I am misunderstanding them.

I should be clear that since all the data is related, there is no advantage gained from splitting the database.

Is there a way to conditionally display zeroes and otherwise suppress them?

Comment: Your overall requirements are unclear. With regard to your specific questions, the only way to suppress display of zero's, yet have some of them display, would be to enter those you wish to display as Text (either format the cell as Text before entering the zero, precede the 0 with a single quote **'**, or have it be text as the output of a formula.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the original columns, and insert two other columns pulling their values from them, and using a formula to suppress the zeros. When you wanted a zero displayed, you would just overwrite the formula.

For example: Column A is your original column with zeros, which you want to suppress. You would hide column A, and in Column B, enter: 
`=if(A1 = 0,"",A1)`
This will suppress the zero. If you want to explicitly enter a zero, just do so, in column B. It will overwrite the formula and show a zero.

For safety's sake, you may also want to add conditional formatting to show when columnA <> columnB, to make sure that the formulas don't get accidentally overwritten in information that doesn't match the actual data hidden in A.

If this works for you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. :-)